# Undefined method confirmed_at when using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-confirmable

I'm getting the following error when trying to use the `:confirmable` module of Devise:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `confirmed_at' for #<AdminUser:0x007f27841d0f30>)
```

My model:

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable,:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  after_create { |admin| admin.send_reset_password_instructions }
  def password_required?
    new_record? ? false : super
  end
end
```

I want to send a confirmation email when `AdminUser` is created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not enough to merely add the `:confirmable` option in the model, you'll also need to add the columns required by Devise into your database table.

Assuming you are using a model `AdminUser`:

```
class AddConfirmableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :admin_users, :confirmation_token,   :string
    add_column :admin_users, :confirmed_at,         :datetime
    add_column :admin_users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
    add_column :admin_users, :unconfirmed_email,    :string

    add_index  :admin_users, :confirmation_token, :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index  :admin_users, :confirmation_token

    remove_column :admin_users, :unconfirmed_email
    remove_column :admin_users, :confirmation_sent_at
    remove_column :admin_users, :confirmed_at
    remove_column :admin_users, :confirmation_token
  end
end
```

Comment: You add :confirmation_token for two times. Either it same or different?

Comment: The second is an index - a way for the db to make sure each token is unique

Comment: As a rule of thumb, an error saying "unrecognized method" for an object typically means *missing db column* ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Simply run the command:

```
rails g migration add_confirmable_to_devise
```

db/migrate/YYYYMMDDxxx_add_confirmable_to_devise.rb

```
class AddConfirmableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration
  # Note: You can't use change, as User.update_all will fail in the down migration
  def up
    add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
    add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token, unique: true
    execute("UPDATE users SET confirmed_at = NOW()")
  end

  def down
    remove_columns :users, :confirmation_token, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at
  end
end
```

For further reference [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users)

Comment: How do you say `NOW()` in sqlite3?

Answer (score 2):

You put `:confirmable` in your AdminUser model. So you need to have columns for confirmable functions including `confirmed_at`.

You should have a migration file which Devise generated. In that file, you need to remove comment out for `confirmable` columns including `created_at`.